# Using Service accounts with Google APIs

Tags: google-api, service-accounts

What I don't understand with Google Service accounts is why they require a user account when you authenticate.

For example:

```
SCOPES = ["http://some_scope"]
ADMIN_EMAIL = "some_Admin@some_domain" credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file( SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES ) credentials = credentials.with_subject(ADMIN_EMAIL) 
adminSDK = build('admin', 'directory_v1', credentials=credentials)
```

To me the whole reason we setup a Service account is to not use user accounts in our code. Is there a way around this?

I have the SCOPES setup on the Service account. Basically, the same ones defined in my code. But unless I use the .with_subject in the credentials and put in my admin account, it will not connect. I get a 400 Error "Invalid Input."

Answer (score 0):

A service account is a dummy user.  It has its own drive account for example where it can access files within in its account.  It cant access files within my drive account unless I grant it access to it like I would any other user.  (this is just an example)

You are using the directory_v1 api, which is the api used to access users (and other stuff) within a google workspace domain.

The service account doesn't have any access to this, as its not a user on your domain, and its defiantly not an admin on your domain.  You need to grant it access, the way that is done is though impersonation.  You configure domain wide delegation within your workspace account to allow the service account to impersonate any user on your workspace domain.

In order for the service account to impersonate a user you need to declare what user that  you want to impersonate in this case you are impersonating some_Admin@some_domain.  Now for all intensive purposes the service account is some_Admin@some_domain.

Again without impersonation the service account doesn't have access to your domain as its not a user on your domain.

> To me the whole reason we setup a Service account is to not use user accounts in our code.

To clarify things. The whole reason you are setting up a service account is so that you do not need to prompt a user for authorization in order to access their data.  Service accounts still need access.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I looked everywhere to find out why I needed my admin account associated with the credentials. This cleared things up for me!

Comment: Welcome to stack remember to accept the answer if it helped you.